# GroupExpression by breaking year up

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am doing an average for the last six months from a select date in my report. Right now everything works and generally lines up correctly. What I need is to break up my GroupExpression so that it does:

```
months 7-12 in 2013 group with months 1-6 in 2014
months 7-12 in 2014 group with months 1-6 in 2015
months 7-12 in 2015 group with months 1-6 in 2016
```

Right now I am using:

```
=DatePart("yyyy", CDATE(Fields!QuoteDueDate.Value))
```

But that only breaks them up by the year. So all of the months of 2014 are together, and so on. Does anyone know how I can create the divisions I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically if month is greater than 6 you want it to be included in the next year?  How about:

```
=DatePart("yyyy", CDATE(Fields!QuoteDueDate.Value)) 
 + IIF(DatePart("m", CDATE(Fields!QuoteDueDate.Value)) > 6, 1, 0)
```

Depending on the complexity of your report, you may want to add this as a field in your query and group on that instead.

Comment: This is pretty close to working, thank you! I've attached a screenshot of how it is spacing the data. Perhaps you have an extra IIF or something I could add that will break it up more properly

Comment: Okay, your fix worked. What happened was I needed to SORT after the fact first by the year, then by the date. Thank you again for your help!!

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't think after the fact sorting would be necessary but I guess that would depend on what other grouping/expressions exist on the report; anyway, glad you got it working!